# Search select2 dropdown aside from id and text values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown for a mobile phone country code. The `id` value is for the actual country code e.g. +1, +61, +86, etc. and the `text` value of the dropdown is configured as `${countryCode} (${countryTwoLetterCode})` e.g. +1 (US)

The issue is that the user can only search for the `text` part of the select2. Is there a way that I can possibly add a hidden searchable value i.e. the full country name such that if I search for the string *United* then it will show results for US and UK i.e. +1 (US) and +44 (GB)

This is how the select2 data format looks like based from their [documentation][1]

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    }
  ]
}


  [1]: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I figured out a solution for this one by adding a new property in the `data` object of the select2 during initialization such that the list of object will be like this

```
[
    {
      id: '+44',
      text: '+44 (GB)',
      dataValue: 'United Kingdom'
    },
    {
      id: '+1',
      text: '+1 (US)',
      dataValue: 'United States'
    }
]
```

The new property `dataValue` is then used when we implement a [custom matcher](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched)

```
function matchCustom(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }

    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }

    if (typeof data.dataValue === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }

    if (data.text.toLowerCase().includes(params.term.toLowerCase())) {
        return data;
    }

    if (data.dataValue.toLowerCase().includes(params.term.toLowerCase())) {
        return data;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Finally, the custom matcher function will be included in the select2 initialization.

```
$('#country-code-dropdown').select2({
    data: data,
    matcher: matchCustom
});
```